# awk print output redirection

Tags: command-line, bash, printing, console, awk

I am writing a bash script, and in that bash script I have a line similar to this:

```
awk '/TextToBeMatched/ { print; print "TextToInsert"; next }1' "/Path/to/specified/file.extension"
```

And currently what it does is finds "TextToBeMatched" in the specified file, and then replaces it with "TextToInsert". But I would like it to instead of then printing the output to the console session, I would like it to print to a file, I guess that I would do this with output redirection, so how exactly would I do this?

I read about output redirection with `awk` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html), but it was not so much help with my code.

Comment: `awk >/path/to/output '/Tex...`?

Comment: @muru: I just get `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'` then.

Comment: tell me you didn't put those periods as is..

Comment: @muru: Of course not! :D

Comment: then it's decidedly odd, since the redirection in my command is done by the shell and awk shouldn't be aware of it.

Comment: @muru: Oh wait, suddenly started working! :D Odd... But it's still not doing what it should, as the output file is blank, it just deletes all the contents and then does nothing.

Comment: eek. Are you redirecting to the same file? In that case, use `-i inplace` instead of the redirection.

Comment: @muru: I was redirecting to the same file, but decided to test in another file, but still blank.

Comment: @muru: And for the `-i inplace` thing, how exactly would that change the code? In other words could you show me where I would put that by showing me my code with that there instead? Because I tried what I thought and just got this: `awk: not an option: -i`.

Comment: `-i` needs GNU awk, so: `gawk -i inplace '/T...'`.

Comment: @muru: Does not appear to be installed... Will install it now...

Comment: If you need help with commands, you need to post the command and any errors you get

Comment: @muru: It works now! Thanks! :) Could you please convert that into an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the output of `awk` to a file, simply use redirection:

```
awk > /path/to/output/file ...
```

Since the shell handles the redirection and empties the output file, you cannot use the same file for both input and output - by the time awk gets to it, the file would have been truncated by the shell.

With GNU awk, you can use the in-place editing plugin to save the output to the same file:

```
gawk -i inplace ...
```

This works much the same way `sed -i` does.